# How to use ScrollTo() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, screen

I want to create a body larger than the actual screen, then I want to use something like scrollTo() to move the screen on the position of a div and I want that div to be centered on the screen.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/635a7s9u/8/)

HTML

```
<div id="first">
First Step
</div>

<div id="second">
Second Step
</div>

<div id="menu">
<button onclick="scrollFirst()">
first step
</button>
<button onclick="scrollSecond()">
second step
</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

#first {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 350px;
  top: 350px;
}

#second {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 550px;
  top: 750px;
}
```

JS

```
function scrollFirst() {
    window.scrollTo(350, 350);
}

function scrollSecond() {
        window.scrollTo(550, 750);
}
```

Comment: Change your JavaScript load type to one of the "No wrap" option in your fiddle. Your script looks fine

Answer (score 0):

You have not properly linked your html and .js file. Because of which your functions are not working.

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

#first {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 350px;
  top: 350px;
}

#second {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 550px;
  top: 750px;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <div id="first">
          First Step
        </div>
        <div id="second">
          Second Step
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
          <button onclick="scrollFirst()">
            first step
          </button>
          <button onclick="scrollSecond()">
            second step
          </button>
        </div>
        <script>
          function scrollFirst() {
            window.scrollTo(350, 350);
          }
          function scrollSecond() {
            window.scrollTo(550, 750);
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```